# Ajax load php into div giving me issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been hammering away at this for a couple of days trying to resolve it before turning to StackOverflow. But I simply can't see where I'm going wrong.

All I want to do is on document load, bring in dansearch.php into the "displayresults" Div with the following code.

Can anyone shed any light here on how to fix this and more importantly why so I can fully understand the issue? Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#displayresults").load("dansearch.php");
    });
</script>
<div id="displayresults"></div>
```

Comment: Any errors? Have you open browser console?

Comment: 1) check the right path of php file; 2) is div visible? z-index?

Comment: Yes I've opened the console but I can't see an error there. The path to the php file is correct. And I have no css applied to the Div itself in regards to z-indexing.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 possibilities, if your code is not working,

1. `Jquery inclusion` may not proper.
2. Your `php page` or its location is not correct.

Comment: You can check #1 by including an `alert(...)` in your `documentReady` function - if it fires JQuery is probably OK. For number #2, I suggest using your browsers debugging tools. For example, if you are using Chrome, press F12 and go to the Network tab. Then execute your AJAX request - you will see exactly which URL is called as well as the response status and any content that the PHP script sends back.

Comment: Thanks Rohan - The Jquery inclusion is fine as it's within the header and all the other ajax code seems to be fine. - I have now used the full path to the php file which does a very very basic echo of a string. The php file works perfectly when loaded on it's own in the browser. Unfortunately it still does not work :/

Comment: Then please do some debugging as per Pinal and my comments.

Comment: @user3279268, unless you explain what precisely "does not work" mean, all the answers would be only guesses. What error are you getting?

Comment: or you can use `die('test');` at the first line of your `php file`.

Comment: Compuchip & Pinal - Through the Network tab in the debugging tool the file dansearch.php is simply not loaded or called. No sign of it. WHat extra information can I give to help? I can't see any errors through the chromes debug or Firebug.

Comment: Compuchip - I've inserted the alert as you suggested, that does not display either! [code]<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("I am an alert box!");
    $("#displayresults").load("dansearch.php");
});
</script>[code]

Comment: SOLVED!! - Thanks! [code]<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   alert("this is an alert");
    $("#displayresults").load("dansearch.php");
});
</script>[code]

Answer (score -1):

Use a [.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("dansearch.php", function(data) {
            $("#displayresults").html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="displayresults"></div>
```

Comment: This is just an uglier way of writing what `.load` already does - if you have an good reason to believe this would solve the problem then please explain.